# Shortest distance between two particles whose position vectors depend on time

Tags: vectors

## The Question

At time $t$, two particles have position vectors given by **r**$_1(t)$ and **r**$_2(t)$ where
$$\mathbf{r}_1=\mathbf{a}_1+\mathbf{b}_1\left(t-t_1\right)$$
$$\mathbf{r}_2=\mathbf{a}_2+\mathbf{b}_2\left(t-t_2\right)$$
Find the minimum seperation of the particles.

Show that, at this seperation, $(t_1-t_2)$ is given by
$$(t_1-t_2)=\frac{(\mathbf{a}_2-\mathbf{a}_1).\left[(\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2)\times(\mathbf{b}_1-\mathbf{b}_2)\right]}{(\mathbf{b}_1.\mathbf{b}_2)^2-(\mathbf{b}_1.\mathbf{b}_1)(\mathbf{b}_2.\mathbf{b}_2)}.$$

## My Attempt

So for the first part I used that the shortest distance is in the direction perpendicular to the lines that describe the paths, such that $d_{min}=\left|(\mathbf{a}_1-\mathbf{a}_2).\mathbf{n}\right|$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is given by $\mathbf{n}=\frac{\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2}{\left|\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2\right|}$. This gave me
$$d_{min}=\left|(\mathbf{a}_1-\mathbf{a}_2).\frac{\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2}{\left|\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2\right|}\right|.$$

For the second part, I said that $\mathbf{d}_{min}$ intersects $\mathbf{r}_1$ at the point where $\mathbf{d}_{min}=\mathbf{r}_1$, so:
$$(\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2)=\mathbf{a}_1+\mathbf{b}_1(t-t_1)$$
$$t-t_1=\frac{(\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2)-\mathbf{a}_1}{\mathbf{b}_1}$$
And similarly for $\mathbf{r}_2$,
$$t-t_2=\frac{(\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2)-\mathbf{a}_2}{\mathbf{b}_2}$$
However, when I take one away from the other I can't seem to get what the question wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost done it.
You cannot divide by vector, you have to use scalar product to separate $t$.
The trick is to multiply both sides of equation by $\cdot \, \vec b_1 / \|\vec b_1\|^2$

$$
t-t_1 = \frac{(\vec b_1 \times \vec b_2 )\cdot \vec b_1 - \vec a_1\cdot\vec b_1}{\| \vec b_1\|^2}
$$

$$
t-t_2 = \frac{(\vec b_1 \times \vec b_2 )\cdot \vec b_2 - \vec a_2\cdot \vec b_2}{\| \vec b_2\|^2}
$$

Below I also attached bonus, i.e. another approach for the problem.
I hope this will help too!

To obtain the shortest distance one can minimize the relative position between particles

$$\vec w(t) =\vec r_1(t) -\vec r_2(t) =\vec w_0 +\vec v t,$$

where initial relative position $\vec w_0 =\vec a_1 -\vec a_2 -\vec b_1 t_1 +\vec b_2 t_2$ and relative velocity $\vec v =\vec b_1 - \vec b_2$.

Let's define a (non-negative) function $D(t)$

$$D(t) =\vec w^\mathsf{T}\vec w =\vec  w(t)\cdot \vec w(t),$$

then calculate derivative with respect to time $t$ and compare it with $0$

$$\frac d{dt}D(t) = 2 \vec w(t) \cdot \frac d{dt} \vec w(t) = 0 $$

We end up with the scalar product equation

$$
\vec w(t) \cdot \frac d{dt} \vec w(t) = 0
$$

First, let's calculate $\frac d{dt} \vec w(t)$

$$
\frac d{dt} \vec w(t) = \vec v
$$

Finally,

$$
(\vec w_0 +\vec v t_{\text{min}}) \cdot \vec v = 0
$$

$$
t_{\text{min}} = -\frac{\vec w_0 \cdot \vec v}{\| \vec v \|^2}= - \frac{(\vec a_1 -\vec a_2 -\vec b_1 t_1 +\vec b_2 t_2)\cdot (\vec b_1-\vec b_2)}{\| \vec b_1 - \vec b_2\|^2}
$$